# MVVM Light RaisePropertyChanged Error

Tags: vb.net, lambda, mvvm-light

I followed examples of `RaisePropertyChanged` for the MVVM Light libraries in a WPF application. This seems like it should be valid. Event the code hints seem to think so. But when I build, Visual Studio gives me an error and then highlights `RaisePropertyChanged` with light blue squiggleys. Anyone seen this issue? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

```
Private _selectedServerInstance As String
Property SelectedServerInstance As String
  Get
      Return _selectedServerInstance
  End Get
  Set(value As String)
      _selectedServerInstance = value
      RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Me.SelectedServerInstance) //Error on build
  End Set
End Property

' Looks ok until I build. The Error for each line with RaisePropertyChanged using a lambda property selector is:
' error BC30518: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'RaisePropertyChanged' can be called with these arguments:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for RaisePropertyChanged:
References required to assemblies 'System.Linq.Expressions', 'System.Runtime', 'System.ObjectModel'.

Check References in your project.

Answer (score 0):

System.Runtime and System.ObjectModel are not in the list of references to choose.  Is this because they are 'facade' references, and rarely get used except in the crazy case of mvvm-light?